# Microsoft Excel 2007: When trying to save - "File in use. Try again later"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, lock

When I open an Excel document from server, edit and then try to save the changed document, I get the message that "path\filename is in use. Try again later".

I can use "save as" and save a new instance of the document - but if I then continue to edit and try to save the new changes, same thing happens with the new instance.

On the Windows Server (2008) I open the tool Share And Storage Management > Manage Open Files, where I can see three open instances related to my document:

1) path\~$filename
2) path\filename
3) path\filename:{GUID}

No 1 and 3 is in read/write mode, no 2 only read. Does this provide any hint of what's happening?

Comment: Check the share and folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible fault of a security software locking files in the background.
I've experienced similar issues myself (when using Beyond Compare) and found that [turning off the Microsoft Security Essentials 'Real Time Protection'](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2025707/how-to-temporarily-disable-microsoft-security-essentials.html) solved my problem.

I.e. constant save errors disappeared as soon as I turned off the MSSE Real Time Protection.

See the following discussion in the MS Virus and Malware forum for more details:
["Real Time Protection" causes "Locked File" errors when saving an open Excel 2007 .xlsm file](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_scanning/real-time-protection-causes-locked-file-errors/d5588e63-5466-455f-be57-88dee9109374?page=1)

Comment: Revisiting the issue it seems that the MSSE, although part of the problem, may not be the only culprit. I've yet to investigate further to entirely get rid of the 'cannot save file' error.